# Добавление виджета QListWidget как страницы вкладки QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlistwidget, qtabwidget

Необходимо реализовать при создании вкладки `Tab Widget` добавление на нее элемента `listWidget`.

Каким образом можно это реализовать?

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton


Form , _ = uic.loadUiType('form.ui')

class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Form):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_data)
        self.gridTabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.tabChanged)
    def tabChanged(self):
        #нажатие на вкладку
        print('tab was', self.gridTabWidget.currentIndex())

    def add_data(self):
        #нажатие на кнопку
        #добавление вкладки
        self.gridTabWidget.addTab(QWidget(), 'new user')


if __name__ =="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

> int QTabWidget::[**addTab**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#addTab)(QWidget *page, const QString &label)
>
> Добавляет вкладку с заданной страницей и меткой в ​​виджет вкладки и возвращает индекс вкладки
> на панели вкладок. Право собственности на страницу передается QTabWidget.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabWidget, QWidget, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication, QMessageBox


class ListWidget(QListWidget):                                                    # +++ ListWidget()
    def _clicked(self,item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "You clicked: "+item.text())


Form , _ = uic.loadUiType('child_window.ui')                                      # !!! child_window.ui

class Ui(QWidget, Form):                                                          # QDialog
    def __init__ (self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_data)
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.tabChanged)
        
    def tabChanged(self):
        #нажатие на вкладку
        print('tab was', self.tabWidget.currentIndex())

    def add_data(self):
        listWidget = ListWidget()                                                 # +++ ListWidget()
        listWidget.addItems(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", ])           # +++
        listWidget.itemClicked.connect(listWidget._clicked)                       # +++
            
        self.tabWidget.addTab(listWidget, 'new user')                             # +++ listWidget


if __name__ =="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui()
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**child_window.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1191</width>
    <height>941</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
   <item>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>940</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
       <property name="tabPosition">
        <enum>QTabWidget::West</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="currentIndex">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
        <attribute name="title">
         <string>Tab 1</string>
        </attribute>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <item>
          <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
           <property name="rowCount">
            <number>5</number>
           </property>
           <row/>
           <row/>
           <row/>
           <row/>
           <row/>
           <column>
            <property name="text">
             <string>A</string>
            </property>
           </column>
           <column>
            <property name="text">
             <string>B</string>
            </property>
           </column>
           <column>
            <property name="text">
             <string>C</string>
            </property>
           </column>
           <column>
            <property name="text">
             <string>D</string>
            </property>
           </column>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
        <attribute name="title">
         <string>Tab 2</string>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев почему вы никак не реагируете на предоставленные вам ответы? Вы читали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour